# Who reads the help center?

Tags: discussion, help-center

Are there any statistics on how many people read the documentation in the [help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help)? Are new community members reading the help center, or is it mostly members who already have Stack Exchange experience?

Comment: *read*: yes, *understand*: no, *follow the offered guidance*: definitely not ...

Comment: Most of them, think they know everything. They think it's all standard bs. I don't think anyone new even attempts to read it.

Comment: People who read documentation probably don't need to. Those who should probably won't. Documentation exists for people who don't use it.

Comment: Reply to all of the previous comments: [CITATION NEEDED]